# Run linux without install?

Tags: kali-linux

Is there (on official site) Linux that I can download and run with VM?

I want for ex. `kali` without install.

Comment: Many Linux distributions provide an USB key to be used without installation

Answer (score 1):

**Kali VM Image**

- Kali official website  provides *[Kali Linux VMware and VirtualBox Image Downloads](https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-vmware-virtualbox-image-download/)*

**Live CD**

- [livecdlist](https://livecdlist.com/) share links for  *liveCD* version for various Linux distributions.
- [Kali-Linux Live CD](https://livecdlist.com/kali-linux/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to workaround and its simple Download Live (Linux Flavor) ISO. You can Use Live Flavor of any Some Linux OS like CentOS, Kali Linux, Ubuntu, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Tails`, which focuses on anonymity and privacy. Just set up a virtual machine without HDD and run `Tails` from it's RAM-memory as a Live-CD:

[Tails - Privacy for anyone anywhere](https://tails.boum.org/)

All basically required programs are already contained (LibreOffice, Gimp, videoplayer, etc.). If you need more programs, you can easily set up a root-password when booting `Tails` and install them on the common way via terminal and `apt-get install`.